# Что такое "непохоже"?

Tags: синтаксис

Надо определить вид придаточного предложения:

> *Непохоже, чтобы его взяли в армию.*

Я определила как изъяснительное. У меня вопрос: что такое "**непохоже**"? Какая функция в предложении у этого слова? (моя версия вводное слово, но не уверена)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Непохоже, чтобы его взяли в армию.**

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. Союз ЧТОБЫ имеет значение ирреальной модальности (выражает **сомнение, неуверенность**).

Поэтому может показаться, что непохоже – это вводное слово с тем же значением неуверенности. Но если это вводное слово, то где же тогда сложное предложение с изъяснительным придаточным?

Поэтому непохоже – **предикативное наречие** (или слово категории состояния, что одно и то же), в словаре указано:  наречие и **в знач. сказ.**; непохоже, чтобы….

В данном случае главное (безличное) предложение состоит из одного слова – сказуемого ***непохоже.***

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

*Непохоже, чтобы его взяли в армию.*

Непохоже - категория состояния в роли сказуемого безличного предложения.  Вводное было бы похоже: Его взяли, похоже, в армию.

Придаточное действительно изъяснительное.

Comment: @ Людмила, а в словаре написано, что это наречие. Просто непохоже на слова категории состояния.

Comment: категория состояния - это и есть предикативное наречие (наречие в роли сказуемого). Категория  состояния стала самостоятельной частью речи совсем недавно, а словарь составлялся давно.

Answer (score 0):

Если можно так выразиться, слова "похоже/непохоже" - логические антонимы друг друга.

- Его взяли в армию? - Непохоже...
- Его не взяли в армию? - Похоже...

Проверочные предложения - синонимы по смыслу. 
Стало быть, "изреченец" склонен утверждать отрицание армейского призыва.

[Невозможно поверить — составное глагольное сказуемое. Невозможно — предикативное наречие.](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-000000005a97ef7775c251c2977eef8a)